# Conflict of libnfsidmap files while running 'dnf update' on Fedora 30

Tags: updates, fedora, conflict

I run `sudo dnf update` on my Fedora 30 and after downloading packages I got this error:

```
    [DRPM] hplip-common-3.19.12-1.fc30_3.19.12-2.fc30.x86_64.drpm: done            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           677 kB/s | 1.0 GB     26:51     
Delta RPMs reduced 1066.4 MB of updates to 1066.3 MB (0.1% saved)
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/man/man5/idmapd.conf.5.gz from install of nfs-utils-1:2.4.2-3.rc3.fc30.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libnfsidmap-1:2.3.3-7.rc2.fc30.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

Please, tell me, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a better solution than to exclude `nfs-utils` packages from upgrade as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532587/fedora-30-dnf-upgrade-problem). That works for me.